# Tracing AWS Step Functions with Splunk (via X-Ray)

Tags: splunk, aws-xray, distributed-tracing

AWS supports tracing Step Functions with X-Ray with a one click instrument step. Once activated, the step function context is propagated through all the lambda functions.

Can Splunk Observability Suite (APM) use the x-ray context data? Or is there another way to trace AWS step functions in splunk APM?

Answer (score 0):

Step function handles the x-ray trace context internally and is not exposed to  outside. Within the Lambda function, you can still get the trace context from the `_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID` environment variable if that fits your use case, however it will different for each lambda function within the StepFunction state machine.